# How to bypass/disable UAC in setup Installation

Tags: inno-setup, nsis, advanced-installer

Folk,

I need to bypass UAC, through my Installer. Please note I am using InnoSetup/NSIS/Advanced Installer. I have tried all settings like SILENT / VERYSILENT but nothing has worked.

Help me out :)

Regards

Subh

Comment: What do you mean with bypass ? Without some serious hack you won't be able to workaround UAC at all. You can run your installer with lower rights if you set the [`PrivilegesRequired`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_privilegesrequired) to a value different from `admin`, which is the default value. That will stop showing the UAC dialog for admin rights, but as a consequence, you won't be able to write e.g. to a Program Files directory (but there's more than this).

Answer (score 3):

You cannot bypass UAC, the user is in control, that is the whole point of UAC! If you want to do machine wide changes that require Administrator privileges there is no way around it.

The only way to avoid it is to do per-user installs into [local]appdata & HKCU (Like Chrome etc). To avoid legacy setup detection you should use `PrivilegesRequired`/`RequestExecutionLevel` and only ask for lower/user privileges...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys :)

I guess I fave found one solution of it, like If I do the following before Installing my EXE for temporary then on post Installation I revert it. then, I hope my purpose get solved.

[Registry]
Root: "HKLM"; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System"; ValueType: dword; ValueName: "ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin"; ValueData: "0x00000000"

If anybody like to discuss on this ,

Here I am at skype : subh.anand

Comment: You will need tho elevate the process to write to this key and for this the UAC prompt will be shown.

Comment: Yes very true, thanks for your comment .. I can do it through Installation script.

Comment: That's very bad way and I hope I won't meet such installer. Consider the situation if the setup unexpectedly crash and this setting will remain set in user's registry.

Comment: Do you know any other way to do this, please share with us .. Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings, Recovery, Advanced Restart. Press Trobleshoot, More Options, and Command Prompt. Then type in `ren Utilman.exe Utilman1.exe` `ren cmd.exe Utilman.exe`. Then go to the login screen, click the dotted power button and you have an admin command prompt!

Comment: Note: it dosen't work with Bitlocker